# mpm_prefork values for 2-4 GB RAM

Tags: ubuntu, performance, apache-2.4, mpm-prefork

I have bought new linode (1GB).

On this page :https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/lamp/install-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04

Linode says:

> Below are the suggested values for a 1GB Linode:

File:**/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf**

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers            2
        MinSpareServers         6
        MaxSpareServers         12
        MaxRequestWorkers       39
        MaxConnectionsPerChild  3000
</IfModule>
```

But I'll plan to upgrade 2GB OR 4GB machine. What should be above values for 2GB or 4GB machine and WHY?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: What is your average Apache process size? How much memory do you need for other applications, e.g. MySQL, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your average Apache process size to get usage x MB. Consider how much memory you want to keep available for other processes y MB and use this formula for prefork.

```
(Total RAM – yMB)/xMB = MaxRequestWorkers
```

NOTE: the "y" value will always be *at least* 500 MB just for Apache itself and the operating system, and may well need to be more depending on other applications.

As to the other values, the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html) repeatedly advises against raising these values except "on very busy sites," of which by definition a site having only 2-4 GB total RAM will never be. The following will be good:

```
StartServers         2
MinSpareServers      5
MaxSpareServers     10
```

For additional reference, you can look at the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html#hardware) for performance tuning this issue.